Hyperparameter tuning with BayesOpt
I wanted to tune the hyperparameters for a Xgboost regression model. My dataset has 11 features and rough 50,000 observations. What are the optimal / practical values of initial_points and n_iter?
I tried initial_point=10 and n_iter=100, but I am not sure whether these values are optimal.
